# An integral identity with a complex parameter

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Conjecture**: For $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$, we have
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{|z-\cos x|}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{|z^{2}-1}|}.
$$
I know it is true for $z\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$ but not in general.

Comment: Please show the own attempts, providing context is important. You know "it" is true for a real $z$ avoiding the interval $[-1,1]$?! Then please show the proof.

Comment: Considering that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{z-\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{z^2-1}} $$ holds for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ (and with an appropriate choice of branch cut of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$), your question is essentially the same as whether $|\cdot|$ and integral commute. And this is in general false. For example, when $z=i$, $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|i-\cos x|}\approx2.62206, \qquad\text{whereas}\qquad \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{|i^2-1|}}\approx2.22144.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you! It's a strong numerical evidence that the conjecture is false, indeed.

Comment: @dan_fulea It is not necessary, now. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the function

$$f(z) = \frac{dx}{|z-\cos x|}$$
is an even function. Hence,

$$
I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{|z-\cos x|} =  \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{|z-\cos x|}
$$

If you do the following substitution:

$$ \cos x = \frac{w+w^{-1}}{2} = \frac{w^2+1}{2w}$$

$$dx = \frac{dw}{wi}$$

$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{|z-\cos x|} =  \frac{1}{i} \oint_{|w|=1} \frac{1}{|w^2+2wz+1|} dw $$

your integral is transformed in a contour integral round the unit complex circle

If $z\in \mathbb{R}$, the function

$$ g(w) = \frac{1}{|w^2+2wz+1|} = \frac{1}{|w+\sqrt{z^2+1}+z||w-\sqrt{z^2+1}+z|}$$ has two singularities:

$$ w_{1} = -\sqrt{z^2-1}-z$$
$$ w_{2} = \sqrt{z^2-1}-z$$

To apply the residue theorem, one of the singularites has to be inside the unit circle:

$$|w_{1}|<1 \Longrightarrow z<-1 $$

$$|w_{2}|<1 \Longrightarrow z>1 $$

Then if $z<- 1$ then

$$I =  \frac{1}{i} \oint_{|w|=1} \frac{1}{|w^2+2wz+1|} dw = 2\pi \operatorname{Res}(g,w_{1}) = 2\pi \lim_{w \to -\sqrt{z^2-1}-z} \frac{w+\sqrt{z^2+1}+z}{|w+\sqrt{z^2+1}+z||w-\sqrt{z^2+1}+z|} = \frac{2\pi}{|-2\sqrt{z^2+1}|} = \frac{\pi}{|\sqrt{z^2+1}|}$$

If $z>1$ then

$$I =  \frac{1}{i} \oint_{|w|=1} \frac{1}{|w^2+2wz+1|} dw = 2\pi \operatorname{Res}(g,w_{2}) = 2\pi \lim_{w \to -\sqrt{z^2-1}+z} \frac{w-\sqrt{z^2+1}+z}{|w+\sqrt{z^2+1}+z||w-\sqrt{z^2+1}+z|} = \frac{2\pi}{|2\sqrt{z^2+1}|} = \frac{\pi}{|\sqrt{z^2+1}|}$$

Note that we have used the following property to calculate these limits:

If $w=x+iy$

$$ \lim_{x\to a, y\to 0} \frac{w}{|w|} = \lim_{x\to a, y\to 0} \frac{x+iy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{|x^2|} = \lim _{x \to a} \frac{x}{|x|} = \operatorname{sign}(a)$$

Hence we can conclude

$$ 
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{|z-\cos x|}=\frac{\pi}{|\sqrt{z^{2}-1}|} \quad z\in \mathbb{R}\backslash[-1,1] } $$

**The statement is not true in general**

Consider $z=i$,

The left hand side is

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{|i-\cos x|} dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}} dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2 x}}dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x}} dx = \sqrt{2}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\approx 2.62 $$

The integral converges and the solution is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. However, the right hand side of the formula

$$\frac{\pi}{|\sqrt{i^{2}-1}|} =\frac{\pi}{|\sqrt{-2}|}  = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 2.22$$

So

$$ 
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{|i-\cos x|}\neq \frac{\pi}{|\sqrt{i^{2}-1}|} $$

Comment: Note that the software sometimes uses a different notation to evaluate elliptic integrals https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticK.html

Comment: Very nice, thank you!